# XML sitemap syntax for canonical pages

Tags: php, xml, mobile, sitemap, canonical-link

I'm using PHP and XML DOM to dynamically add new children to my sitemap as new web pages are created. The code uses XML DOM and addchild(); to update the file.

I am developing my mobile compatible version of the site and want bots to see canonical pages correctly.

Google for example recommends this format (From google-webmaster dev) :

```
  <url>
   <loc>http://www.example.com/page-1/</loc>
     <xhtml:link
      rel="alternate"
      media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"
      href="http://m.example.com/page-1" />
  </url>
```

The tag

```
<xhtml:link BuNcH oF StUfFD HeRe />
```

doesn't look right to me? How is this a properly formatted XML child element?

Is the syntax below an acceptable alternative?:

```
  <url>
   <loc>http://www.example.com/page-1/</loc>
     <xhtml:link>
      rel="alternate"
      media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"
      href="http://m.example.com/page-1" 
     </xhtml:link>
  </url>
```

Why this is a problem to me is the way I'm developing my sitemap in XML DOM. As far as I know you can only add properly formatted children in XML. Here is my PHP I use to generate my sitemap:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
  $imagechild = 'image:image';
  $imageloc = 'image:loc';
   $xml=simplexml_load_file("../sitemap.xml");
    $map = $xml->addChild('url');
    $map->addChild('loc', "http://mywebsite/".$page_pathloc);
    $img = $map->addChild($imagechild, '', 'http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1');
    $img->addChild($imageloc, $img_link);
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
$xml->saveXML('../sitemap.xml');
```

Comment: That stuff after buried in the element are attributes... you should use SimpleXMLNode's addAttribute. i.e. `$node = $xml->addChild('url'); $node->addAttribute("rel", "alternative"); $node->addAttribute("loc", "http://mywebsite/".$page_pathloc");`

Comment: thank you @Orangepill , needed the word attribute, that was the info I needed ;-)